# replace a string with special " ' "

Tags: awk, sed, gsub

I want to find and replace string with special symbol " ' " using gsub of awk.

I tried escape the symbol with \ and even \\ but my code returns > .

```
awk '{ gsub("%27","'",$1); print $1 }' file.txt
```

file.txt:

```
%27SWAY%27
```

I want above to be replaced to 'SWAY'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a single quote in an awk program delineated by single quotes.

One way around that is to assign the quote character to an awk variable with `-v`:

```
echo '%27SWAY%27'| awk -v q="'" '{ gsub("%27",q,$1); print $1 }' 
'SWAY'
```

Another is to use the octal character escape sequence `\047`:

```
$ echo '%27SWAY%27'| awk '{ gsub("%27","\047",$1); print $1 }' 
'SWAY'
```

Finally you can put the awk program in a separate file, in which case the single quote doesn't cause a problem:

```
$ cat a.awk
{ gsub("%27","'",$1); print $1 }

$ echo '%27SWAY%27'| awk -f a.awk
'SWAY'
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use 2nd option using \47. it seems simpler than the other two.

Comment: Always use 3-digit octal `\047` whenever you want a single quote in awk as it's portable across all awks and all contexts (regexps vs strings, search vs replacement, command line vs file script, etc.). `\47` would fail if you had more digits after it (e.g. try `sub(/%27/,"\471")` vs `sub(/%27/,"\0471")`) and even if tempted, don't use the hex `\x27`, see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote

Comment: Thx @EdMorton, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following too.

```
awk '{gsub("%27","\047")} 1'  Input_file
```

Ohh, I just now saw @jas already have this, let me add a `sed` solution now.

```
sed 's/%27/'"'"'/g'  Input_file
```

Or as per @ghoti sir's comment could use in `sed` like:

```
sed "s/%27/'/g" input_file
```

Comment: Or, heck, `sed "s/%27/'/g" input_file`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BASH string expansion if your BASH is a recent one:

```
$ echo "%27SWAY%27" | awk $'{gsub("%27","\'",$1); print $1 }' 
'SWAY'
```

The "$" in front of '{..}' interprets the "\'" for awk.

Comment: Yes. I actually was using it in a bash script and $ did work.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/%27/'\''/g' file
```

Poke a hole through to the underlying shell and use a quoted single quote.